# What is the time complexity of k-means?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, k-means

I was going through the [k-means Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). Based on the algorithm, I think the complexity is `O(n*k*i)` (`n` = total elements, `k` = number of cluster iteration)

So can someone explain me this statement from Wikipedia and how is this NP hard?

> If `k` and `d` (the dimension) are fixed, the problem can be exactly solved in time `O(ndk+1 log n)`, where `n` is the number of entities to be clustered.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It depends on what you call *k*-means.

The problem of finding the global optimum of the [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) objective function

[image]

is NP-hard, where `Si` is the cluster `i` (and there are `k` clusters), `xj` is the `d`-dimensional point in cluster `Si` and `μi` is the centroid (average of the points) of cluster `Si`.

However, running a fixed number `t` of iterations of the [standard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm) takes only `O(t*k*n*d)`, for `n` (`d`-dimensional) points, where `k`is the number of centroids (or clusters). This what practical implementations do (often with random restarts between the iterations).

The standard algorithm only approximates a local optimum of the above function, and so do all the *k*-means algorithms that I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is NP-Hard because there is another well known NP hard problem that can be reduced to (planar) k-means problem. Have a look at the paper [*The Planar k-means Problem is NP-hard*](https://www.imsc.res.in/~meena/papers/kmeans.pdf) (by Mahajan et al.) for more info.