# Are there any limits on k-mean in terms of k points, data dimensionality, and size of data (millions of samples )

Tags: bigdata, data-mining, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset consists of 2 million samples.
I want to use k-means to cluster this dataset into 2000 clusters.
is it ok to use this number of clusters with this data size.

note: feature vector size of each sample is 1000

Comment: It can process the data. But you probably have too many outliers. How will you know if the result is good?

Answer (score 0):

To predict the runtime of an algorithm, you can take a look at it's time complexity. This is a formula that relates the run time to some parameters like for instance the data points and number of clusters in k-means. Information about time complexity in k-means clustering can be found here: [Computational complexity of k-means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634149/computational-complexity-of-k-means)